# Creating custom tick labels in a plot in plotly in Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, contour

I have been trying to create a contour plot using plot.ly in Python (Jupyter Notebook). The data set comprises of 366 units in the X-axis and 216 units in the Y-axis. Hence the axes display values from 0 to 365 and 0 to 215 in the X and Y axes respectively.

- I want to label the X-axis to display equally spaced names of 12 months. ie., Jan, Feb, .., Dec, and Y-axis to show only 3 points labelled -30, 0, and 30.
- I want to create a line through the points of maxima.

How can I do these?

What I've done so far is:

```
fig = [
    go.Contour(
        z=data_set,
        colorscale=[[0, 'rgb(204,229,255)'], [0.15, 'rgb(153,204,255)'],
                    [0.3, 'rgb(102,178,255)'], [1, 'rgb(0,51,102)']]
    )]

py.iplot(fig)
```

where **z** is a list of lists of 366x216 data points (ie., 366 lists inside z each of which contains 216 values). I'm getting a plot as follows: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0XE7.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Mock up some data, give it your best try, and then post that.

Comment: I've added the code and the plot I've been able to produce so far. Hope it helps.

Comment: At last, I could sort out the first problem of custom labeling the plot. But, I still have no idea how to take on the second issue of creating a line connecting the points of maxima in the same contour plot.

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that the first problem of custom labeling can be done as follows:

```
hy = 216/2.0
hx = 366/12.0       

layout=dict(
                xaxis=dict(
                tickvals=[(2*k-1)*hx/2 for k in range(1,13)],
                ticktext=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',]
                ),
                yaxis=dict(
                tickvals=[k*hy for k in range(3)],
                ticktext=[-30, 0, 30]
                )
        )
```

But, I still have no idea how to proceed with the second one.